# Basic authentication not working in node-rest-client node

Tags: python, node.js, rest

I'm using node-rest-client library to call my rest API running a python flask app in a test server. The Node setup and request code is below.

If I add a user token to the request header it words fine, but in the call to obtain the user token using basic auth my python system is successfully authenticating and returning the token with a 200 status, but the flask server is then changing this to a 400 Bad Request. It works fine making the call using Postman.

Is there something missing from my two config objects for node-rest-client?

Cheers.

```
var options_auth = { 
    user: "bob", 
    password: "password",
    mimetypes: {
        json: ["application/json", "application/json;charset=utf-8"]
    } 
};

var Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;
var client = new Client(options_auth);
var method = "/authtoken";

var args = {
    headers: { 
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "api-key": "asf89a7assa98d7sd98d98ds",
        //"token": "dsf98s7dsf98dsf7sd98f7dsf",
        "Accept": "application/json"
    },
    responseConfig: {
        timeout: 1000 //response timeout
    }
};

client.get(Api.url+method, args, function (data, response) {
    // parsed response body as js object 
    // raw response 
    //console.log(response);

    if(Buffer.isBuffer(data)){
        data = data.toString('utf8');
    }
    console.log(data);

    var stringData = data.toString('utf8');

    console.log("String data = "+stringData);

}).on('error', function (err) {
    console.error('Something went wrong with the http client', err);
});
```

Also, spotted these differences between the request headers received by the server:

```
// Node Request fails: 400
  'headers': EnvironHeaders([
        ('Authorization', u'Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXX=='),
        ('Vga-Api-Key', u'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'),
        ('Content-Length', u'0'), 
        ('Connection', u'close'), 
        ('Host', u'127.0.0.1:8080'), 
        ('Accept', u'*/*'), 
        ('Content-Type', u'application/json')]),

  // Postman Request works: 200
  'headers': EnvironHeaders([
        ('Authorization', u'Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXX=='), 
        ('Vga-Api-Key', u'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'), 
   *    ('Content-Length', u''), 
   *    ('Connection', u'keep-alive'), 
        ('Host', u'127.0.0.1:8080'), 
   *    ('Cache-Control', u'no-cache'), 
        ('Accept', u'*/*'), 
        ('Content-Type', u''), 
   *    ('Accept-Encoding', u'gzip, deflate')]),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your setting of the header `Content-Type: application/json` and the probable calling in the server of `request.get_json()` directly, or indirectly via the (deprecated) `request.json` property.

When `get_json()` is called Flask will check to see that a JSON payload has been sent in the body of the request and then parse it if present. That's OK if the request actually contains JSON in the body, but, being a GET request, yours doesn't. In this case, its JSON expectation being unfulfilled, the server raises a `BadRequest` error and returns a HTTP 400 error response.

From what you've shown your request doesn't need to be JSON because the authorisation username and password are passed in the `Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxx` header.

The easiest and best way to fix the problem is to simply omit the content type header.

Alternatively you can tell Flask not to complain if there is no JSON data to parse by passing `silent=True` to `get_json`, but this just papers over the problem and is not a good idea.

Comment: Hi, no I'm not passing anything in the request body so am not extracting JSON on the flask side. Actually I just added the content in an attempt to try and fix the problem :-)

Comment: Actually I just got a version working by removing some actions on the flask side that were unneeded for now, and it worked - I tried another function extracting user data and it worked fine. So maybe it was some kind of timing issue? Its weird and maybe I'll run into this problem again but for now it works. Wouldn't say I'd solved it though, merely side-stepped the issue for now. Also, I'm new to Node, but I'm not seeing much gain in using node-rest-client over the standard http client.

Comment: @Jon: what did you remove?

Comment: Ah, I DID remove something that was JSON related. `if request.json and 'eit' in request.json:` - wonder if it was that, going by what you suggested before. I wasn't expecting the code block to be run but it might have been enough to break it as you describe above.

Comment: I'll try fixing it with "The easiest and best way to fix the problem is to simply omit the content type header."

Comment: That did it. I deleted the content type header and it worked. Excellent, thanks :-)

Comment: @Jon: no worries. BTW `request.json` is a property that calls `get_json()` internally, so `if request.json...` would trigger the problem. Note that `request.json` is deprecated and you should explicitly call `request.get_json()` instead.

Comment: Cool @mhawke. Thanks for the heads up.